# How to align multiple Gridview controls horizontally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to have 2 or more controls(e.g. gridview controls) aligned horizontally.
Optional: I want to have 1 gridview control and 1 Image control in the same row (horizontally).

I tried the following controls..

```
  MultiView: Only vertical alignment possible  
  WebPartZone: It looked good in design mode, but gave me an error (something with the App_Data folder) and I think there must be a more simple approach.
```

I can have  2 Image controls horizontally.But Why not 2 gridviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your Grid view inside Div as per mentioned by mikeshorts or use an another way like use table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</td>
<td>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

or you just use **HorizontalAlign** property like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  HorizontalAlign="Left" >
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"  HorizontalAlign="Right" >
    </asp:GridView>
```

i hope it will work for you.

Comment: The table solution is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: I am having 4 grids, how to arrange 2 are above and 2 are next row

Answer (score 2):

Try putting them as two separate divs.... something like this:

```
<div style="float:left; position:relative;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<div style="float:right; position:relative;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer, it is useful and a first successful solution. Didn´t know about the float:left thing.

Answer (score 1):

HI Please check this aricle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.horizontalalign.aspx

Hope its helpful to you.